# Parsing of .csv file is skipping one row

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

I have an input file that looks like this:

```
SET,LAYOUT,LAYER,NAME
RESTAURANT,RR_FACING1,BACKDROP,restaurant1
RESTAURANT,RR_FACING1,BACKGROUND,chairs1
RESTAURANT,RR_FACING2,BACKDROP,restaurant2
RESTAURANT,RR_FACING3,BACKDROP,restaurant1
RESTAURANT,RR_FACING3,FOREGROUND,potted_plant1
SPACE,SPACE1,BACKDROP,starfield1
SPACE,SPACE2,BACKDROP,starfield2
SPACE,SPACE2,BACKGROUND,planet1
SPACE,SPACE2,FOREGROUND,spaceship1
FOREST,FOREST1,BACKDROP,forest1
FOREST,FOREST1,BACKGROUND,trees1
FOREST,FOREST1,FOREGROUND,bushes1
```

I wrote the following code to parse it.  Import statements not included:

```
full_path_to_file = 'C:\\SAMPLE_INFO.csv'
openfile = open(full_path_to_file)
reader = csv.DictReader(openfile)

headers = next(reader)
layouts_schema = {}

for group1, records1 in itertools.groupby(reader, key=operator.itemgetter("SET")):
    layouts_schema[group1] = {}
    for group2, records2 in itertools.groupby(records1, key=operator.itemgetter("LAYOUT")):
        layouts_schema[group1][group2] = list(records2)
```

This works great, except for one problem.  It skips the first row/value of the key combo RESTAURANT/RR_FACING1/BACKDROP.  It pulls everything correctly except for that first row after the headers.  Thus the output is this:

```
{'FOREST': {'FOREST1': [{'LAYER': 'BACKDROP',
                     'LAYOUT': 'FOREST1',
                     'NAME': 'forest1',
                     'SET': 'FOREST'},
                    {'LAYER': 'BACKGROUND',
                     'LAYOUT': 'FOREST1',
                     'NAME': 'trees1',
                     'SET': 'FOREST'},
                    {'LAYER': 'FOREGROUND',
                     'LAYOUT': 'FOREST1',
                     'NAME': 'bushes1',
                     'SET': 'FOREST'}]},
  'RESTAURANT': {'RR_FACING1': [{'LAYER': 'BACKGROUND',
                            'LAYOUT': 'RR_FACING1',
                            'NAME': 'chairs1',
                            'SET': 'RESTAURANT'}],
            'RR_FACING2': [{'LAYER': 'BACKDROP',
                            'LAYOUT': 'RR_FACING2',
                            'NAME': 'restaurant2',
                            'SET': 'RESTAURANT'}],
            'RR_FACING3': [{'LAYER': 'BACKDROP',
                            'LAYOUT': 'RR_FACING3',
                            'NAME': 'restaurant1',
                            'SET': 'RESTAURANT'},
                           {'LAYER': 'FOREGROUND',
                            'LAYOUT': 'RR_FACING3',
                            'NAME': 'potted_plant1',
                            'SET': 'RESTAURANT'}]},
  'SPACE': {'SPACE1': [{'LAYER': 'BACKDROP',
                   'LAYOUT': 'SPACE1',
                   'NAME': 'starfield1',
                   'SET': 'SPACE'}],
       'SPACE2': [{'LAYER': 'BACKDROP',
                   'LAYOUT': 'SPACE2',
                   'NAME': 'starfield2',
                   'SET': 'SPACE'},
                  {'LAYER': 'BACKGROUND',
                   'LAYOUT': 'SPACE2',
                   'NAME': 'planet1',
                   'SET': 'SPACE'},
                  {'LAYER': 'FOREGROUND',
                   'LAYOUT': 'SPACE2',
                   'NAME': 'spaceship1',
                   'SET': 'SPACE'}]}}
```

Which is missing the following part, which should be the first thing in the RESTAURANT grouping:

```
 {'LAYER': 'BACKDROP',
  'LAYOUT': 'RR_FACING1',
  'NAME': 'restaurant1',
  'SET': 'RESTAURANT'}
```

Hope that makes sense.  Why is it skipping this first row, and only the first row?

Comment: Using a `DictReader` consumes the header row to determine dictionary keys. `headers = next(reader)` is actually consuming your first row of data. Get rid of that line.

Comment: That solved it!  Thank you!  Not sure how I give you credit for the answer, but thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a `DictReader` consumes the header row to determine dictionary keys.

That means this next line of code consumes your first row of data:

```
headers = next(reader)
```

You can get rid of that line.  If you need a list of headers on a `csv.DictReader` object you can do

```
headers = reader.fieldnames
```